# Insert "daterange" field value into PostgreSQL table through JDBC

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, date-range

I have a table in PostgreSQL(9.3) with [daterange](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html) field type.

I can select this field like a String with JDBC, but I cannot Insert it in a table.

What I've tried:

```
PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement("insert into mytable (my_daterange_field) values (?)"); 
stm.setString(1, "[2014-01-02,2014-01-04]");
int i = stm.executeUpdate();
```

and I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "my_daterange_field" is of type daterange but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 168
```

Does anyone have a solution for inserting daterange?
What stm.setXXX should I use? Or maybe I cannot do that because JDBC Driver does not have daterange support...
Maybe there is a third solution?

Thank you.

P.S.

My PostgreSQL JDBC Driver:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>8.4-701.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
insert into mytable (my_daterange_field) values (?::daterange)
```